# MTU 9000 and 1500 when machines with MTU 1500 send data to machines with MTU 9000

Tags: linux, mtu, jumboframes

we have some machines in the cluster

linux machines as `Linux_a , linux_b` are configured with `MTU 1500`

while linux machines - `linux_1 and linux_2` are configured with `MTU 9000`

so

linux machines - `linux_a and linux_b` send heavy data to `linux_1 and linux_2`

is it a problem?

*note - as I understand only scenario as:
send data from linux that configured with MTU 9000 to machine with MTU 1500 - is a problem*

Comment: tcpdump and look for TCP MSS